# I have a error in my code on discord and i use node . and node index.js - Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a discord bot, but running `node index.js` on the file at the bottom of this post gives the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dogli\Documents\GitHub\index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
```

index.js:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = bot.login(TOKEN_SECRET)
bot.on('ready',() =>{
    console.log('this bot is online');})
```

Comment: does `C:\Users\dogli\Documents\GitHub\index.js` exist?

Comment: I hope `NzYyODU3NTEwMTAwNzk1NDAy.X3vQaw.NDq3uZyt4ik7Bm3es0SUQCZc8F4` isn't something you should keep private

Comment: yes `:\Users\dogli\Documents\GitHub\index.js` exist

Comment: How are you executing the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to make `node .` work:

That means that you haven't defined the main file in your package.json, you should give it a look and add your main file there, so, if its `main.js`, replace `bot.js` with `main.js`, etc, etc...

```json
{
  "name": "project name",
  "version": "1.7.1",
  "description": "something",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "dependencies": {
   ...
  }
}
```

And that will make `node .` work instead of throwing errors.

#### A small work around:

<s>Instead of typing `node .` in your console, type `node your-main-file.js`, and your project should start</s>
I misunderstood your question, first, you should cd (go to) your directory where your main file exist's, to do that, open a cmd prompt, and type `cd C:/Path/To/Main/File.js`, and then, type `node main-file.js`.

Please be sure you main file is index.js or main.js or bot.js, typing `node index.js` when a file called index.js dosent exist, and will throw errors.